# Get channel/playlist's last update time with YouTube API v3

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to cache results to reduce the calls I make to the API based on whether something actually changed in the channel/playlist.

Is there a way to know when a channel or playlist was last updated using version 3 of the API?

In the previous version for example `ProfileEntry` had an `Updated` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The YouTube API uses etags for every resource and so you may be able to use them ... it would allow you to send the etag with your request and if nothing has changed, you get back a very quick 304 (so it may not reduce the number of calls you make, but it still reduces latency because your app won't have to wait for large payloads to be returned when your cached version is up-to-date).

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#etags